# spring mvc not bind model to view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm exploring spring mvc but have issue when bind model to view.
My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/advertiser")

public class AdvertiserController {
    @Autowired
    private AdvertiserService advertiserService;
    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable long id){
            Advertiser adv=advertiserService.get(id);
            return new ModelAndView("advertiser/edit","command",adv);
    }
}
```

i also have a edit.jsp file in /WEB-INF/advertiser directory.

My viewresolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

However, i just got 404 error when go to: http://localhost:8080/springmvcdemo/advertiser/edit/1

The error description: /springmvcdemo/WEB-INF/advertiser/edit/1.jsp

It looks like spring is trying to find a 1.jsp file to serve the request instead of serve with edit.jsp as i want.

**UPDATE:**

I just add 1 more function to my controller and it not work also:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView add2(ModelAndView mav){


        mav.addObject("command", new Advertiser());
        mav.setViewName("advertiser/add");

        return mav;
}
```

And the issue is still, the 404 error with the description:

```
/springmvcdemo/WEB-INF/advertiser/add2.jsp
```

I have point the view to "advertiser/add" but spring still trying to find add2.jsp not add.jsp. That make me think i failed in the viewResolver configuration but still not find out what it is.

Comment: Can you share the configuration for the `ViewResolver` ?

Comment: sure: <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

Answer (score 0):

Change the path to `advertiser/edit/1` as follows..

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable long id){
        Advertiser adv=advertiserService.get(id);
        return new ModelAndView("advertiser/edit","command",adv);
}
```

Comment: The request should be serve with edit.jsp view. The number "1" is the variable, it can be 2,3.... I don't think i should fixed something like "advertiser/edit/1" to the view name. Nevermind, try as you said but not success.

Comment: My Bad!. How is the `advertiser` mapping done? Can you share the full code please?

Comment: I just edit my question, It's all my controller with mapping of advertiser

Comment: Since you don't have a file named `1.jsp` and you only need to return the `edit.jsp`, you should change the line as `return new ModelAndView("advertiser/edit","command",adv);`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Oops! so sorry, my bad, i just add {id} after i got your first answer to make a try. Your code now is totally same as my code at first, and it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check point.

**servelt-context.xml**

```
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

**controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/advertiser")
public class AdvertiserController {

    @Autowired
    private AdvertiserService advertiserService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable long id, ModelAndView mav){
         Advertiser adv = advertiserService.getAdvertiserById(id);

         mav.addObject("command", adv);
         mav.setViewName("folder/viewName");

         return mav;
    }
}
```

Example directory : webapp/WEB-INF/views/advertiser/**edit**.jsp

Example case : mav.setViewName(advertiser/**edit**); using viewName.

---

I think to change your code. if your directory WEB-INF/advertiser/**add2**.jsp

**YOUR UPDATE:**

```
mav.setViewName("advertiser/**add2**");
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

Your have file(WEB-INF/advertiser/add and add2.jsp) in directory.

show add.jsp

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/one", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(ModelAndView mav){

         mav.setViewName("advertiser/add");

         return mav;
    }
```

show add2.jsp

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/two", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(ModelAndView mav){

         mav.setViewName("advertiser/add2");

         return mav;
    }
```

Comment: make a change in Servlet context as <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/advertiser/" />

Comment: I have check all the point you said but nothing work. I will update the question again so it should be more clear. I think i have something failed in configuration but i cannot find it out.

Comment: Good lock. you can do it.

Comment: hmm.. You may look at my update. If i set the requestmapping to add2, spring will find add2.jsp. I have added a add2.jsp and it's showed. However what i really want is pointing it to add.jsp not add2.jsp. Adding the name of the view: mav.setViewName("advertiser/add"); doesn't help???

Comment: If i set the requestmapping to add2, spring will find add2.jsp <- Nonono, spring not find add2.jsp and dispatcher servlet handlermapping to SimpleUrlHandlerMapping just find url "/add2".. you use to set setViewName in ModelAndview.

Comment: i know it but it's the strange thing i have to find out. In fact the mapper is good. I put the break point and debug, go to /add2 url and the action in controller is called. I set the View name as "add" as you see above. However at the end, i got add2 view show up.

Comment: No matter what view name i set, my add2 action always show up the add2 view - that exactly my issue in brief.

Comment: You see your view? it`s solve? good. but, I want to see your views directory.

Comment: I see the add2.jsp view. The add.jsp: \WEB-INF\advertiser\add.jsp and the add2.jsp: \WEB-INF\advertiser\add2.jsp.